# How to remove bathtub faucet cartridge?

Tags: plumbing

I have a leaky bathtub faucet, how do I remove this kind of cartridge?

[image: bathtub faucet]

Comment: Do you know the manufacturer or model?  It looks like it should just come out by unscrewing the retaining nut on the front.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that information. I haven't tried that nut, I don't have clearance to turn off the water yet, but wanted to make sure I'm prepared when it's time.

Comment: If it isn't that nut, it doesn't look accessible from the outside of the wall. Best way to prep would be to spray it with some CLR so it comes off easier - it looks pretty calcified.